# How to change languages(translations) dynamically on PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qt-linguist

I wonder if it is possible to change the languages(translations) dynamically without using qt designer to make the UI? That means I don't want to use the function retranslateUi() to update the program interface.

Here is my code, but I'm stuck on lines marked #1 #2 #3. Don't know what I should use to update the interface.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTranslator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, 
QComboBox, QVBoxLayout


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton(self.tr('Start'), self)
        self.label = QLabel(self.tr('Hello, World'), self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.addItem('English')
        self.combo.addItem('中文')
        self.combo.addItem('français')
        self.combo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.change_func)

        self.trans = QTranslator(self)

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)

    def change_func(self):
        print(self.combo.currentText())
        if self.combo.currentText() == '中文':
            self.trans.load('eng-chs')
            _app = QApplication.instance()
            _app.installTranslator(self.trans)
            # 1

        elif self.combo.currentText() == 'français':
            self.trans.load('eng-fr')
            _app = QApplication.instance()
            _app.installTranslator(self.trans)
            # 2

        else:
            _app = QApplication.instance()
            _app.removeTranslator(self.trans) 
             # 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TL; DR;**  It is not necessary to use Qt Designer

---

You should not use Qt Designer necessarily but you should use the same technique, that is, create a method that could be called `retranslateUi()` and in it set the texts using `translate()` instead of `tr()` (for more details read [the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/i18n.html)). Calling that method when you change language for it must use the `changeEvent()` event. For example in your case the code is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.change_func)

        self.trans = QtCore.QTranslator(self)

        self.v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        options = ([('English', ''), ('français', 'eng-fr' ), ('中文', 'eng-chs'), ])
        
        for i, (text, lang) in enumerate(options):
            self.combo.addItem(text)
            self.combo.setItemData(i, lang)
        self.retranslateUi()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def change_func(self, index):
        data = self.combo.itemData(index)
        if data:
            self.trans.load(data)
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().installTranslator(self.trans)
        else:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().removeTranslator(self.trans)

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.LanguageChange:
            self.retranslateUi()
        super(Demo, self).changeEvent(event)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.button.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate('Demo', 'Start'))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate('Demo', 'Hello, World'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then generate the .ts:

```
pylupdate5 main.py  -ts eng-chs.ts
pylupdate5 main.py  -ts eng-fr.ts
```

Then use Qt Linguist to do the translations.

And finally the .qm:

```
lrelease eng-fr.ts eng-chs.qm
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>The complete project you find [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/53349623).</sub>

Comment: lrelease command dont work for me, any idea?

Comment: @Jalkhov The big question is what does it mean: *lrelease command dont work for me*, please be more detailed.

Comment: Ok, sorry. When I try to use it I get `lrelease not recognized as an internal or external command, program or executable batch file.`

Comment: @Jalkhov That error indicates that the lrelease program does not exist so you have to install it and you have 2 options: 1) Install qt or 2) install qt5-applications and replace `lrelease` with `qt5-tools lrelease`

Comment: Thanks, the second option worked for me, I already had pyqt5-tools installed.

Comment: And what if I have several other widgets connected to the main one? Should I take care myself of calling retranslateUi() for each widget?

Answer (score 1):

No you will have to use a technique like Qt Designer does with retranslateUi because the Qt widget system does not have a way to redo the translation on it's own (otherwise QT Designer would be using that to).

Building such a system would require a fundamental change to the widgets as for each string property you would need to know that it contains a translatable string (not a data value) and knowing the original string for looking up the new translation would be best (reversing translations could be ambiguous).

Comment: so that means I have to use qt designer to make the UI and call retranslateUi() in my logical codes when I want to change the language? No other way?

Comment: No you do not have to use Qt designer, eyllanesc explains in more detail how it works.