# installTranslator works only on QMainWindow, not on other windows (Pyqt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to support multiple languages in my PyQt application. I have *.qm files for each language and install my QTranslator on the app instance. It works fine in my main class but doesn't work in the Settings modal.
What is the problem?

this is my code:

run.py

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    translator = QTranslator()
    translator.load(resource_path(r'app_en.qm'))
    app.installTranslator(translator)

    if API.configs.language == 'fa':
        translator.load(resource_path('app_fa.qm'))
        app.installTranslator(translator)
    
    main_window = Main()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec()
```

main.py

```py
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ui_path = resource_path('views', 'main.ui')
        loadUi(ui_path, self)
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        self.config.read("MY_CONFIG_PATH")

        self.settings_btn.clicked.connect(self.open_settings_window)

    def open_settings_window(self):
        from forms.settings import Settings

        settings_window = Settings(self.config, parent=self)
        settings_window.exec()
```

settings.py

```py
class Settings(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, config, parent=None):
        super(Settings, self).__init__(parent)
        ui_file_path = resource_path('views', 'settings.ui')
        loadUi(ui_file_path, self)
```

In qt-designer:
[image]

When running app:
[image]

I guarantee that all this words are in my ts files.

Comment: Translations work on context, so, chances are that your translation doesn't consider the `Settings` dialog, but only applies on the QMainWindow. But we need to know more about your translation files (and how you generated them) in order to provide a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort, trial and error, I finally found the solution to my problem. The issue originated from a place I was entirely sure didn't have any errors (translation files, ts files)! I wasn't using Qt Linguist and manually created tags using the message tag for each translation. However, I had overlooked one point: I was creating all these message tags in the Context block with the name 'MainWindow,' while I should have placed them in the Context block with the tag name 'Dialog.'

app_fa.ts

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="fa">
<context>
    <name>MainWindow</name>
    <message>
        <message>
        <source>capturing</source>
        <translation>عکس برداری</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>saved</source>
        <translation>ذخیره شده‌ها</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>sended</source>
        <translation>ارسال شده‌ها</translation>
    </message>
</context>
<context>
    <name>Dialog</name>
    <message>
        <source>Software</source>
        <translation>نرم افزار</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. your dialog isn't parented so it doesn't inherit any properties from a parent.
2. if your open_settings_window is executed prior to translations being loaded even if you did parent it, odds are the translations would not take effect. Depends on if there is a default retranslateUI() slot in Python.
3. you should really look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349623/how-to-change-languagestranslations-dynamically-on-pyqt5).

Comment: I parented my dialog but don't works

Comment: To the second point you mentioned, could you provide me with a bit more guidance?

Comment: @Yousef That's irrelevant: 1. based on your code, `open_settings_window` is called after the translator has been installed; 2. the parent may give a further context, but it still depends on how the translation file were created. As already said, if you don't give us enough context to understand the problem, we cannot help you. For what we know, the problem could even be a basic typo in the translation files, or a wrong file path for the translation (possibly referring to an old version that wasn't rebuilt after changes).

Comment: I'm sure that the ts and qm files were created and loaded correctly because on the main page the translations are applied properly.
and also add more detail from codes and images to help improve understanding of the problem.

Comment: You were right @musicamante
I should have checked more things.

Comment: parent=none is not parenting a dialog. It needs to have your MainWindow as a parent.