# lrelease: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease' since it links to lrelease itself

Tags: linux, pyqt5

I am trying to code a multilingual app with PyQt5. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349623/how-to-change-languagestranslations-dynamically-on-pyqt5), I've executed `lrelease eng-fr.ts eng-fr.qm` to generate a .qm file but I've got the following error

```
lrelease: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease' since it links to lrelease itself. Check your installation.
```

I couldn't finde any solution in internet. How can I solve this?

Comment: As the error suggests, did you check your installation (possibly by uninstalling and reinstalling again)? How did you install Qt/PyQt?