How to switch gettext language live in PyQt6
I am currently working on a Linux-native GUI for 7-zip and have already completed the menu and toolbar. In them are of course a lot of text snippets that I translate using gettext. It is possible to switch the language of gettext live (just call the .install() method of the wanted translation), but I am stuck on how to update the labels on all the buttons to reflect that change of language in the background, instead of just having new dialogs be in the newly-selected language until the program is restarted.
I hope what I want is possible with not-too-much effort. Otherwise I could also switch to PyQt's built-in translation mechanism, but I'd like to keep using gettext.

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53349623, but I asked this seperately because I don't use PyQt's built-in translation mechanisms unlike the author of the above-mentioned question.

Switching languages with gettext doesn't look like much fun, even for a pure Python project, and the problems are only going to multiply for a GUI application with an event-loop. Qt's i18n support is a fully integrated solution. It's probably not perfect, and PyQt's implementation isn't complete, but it's hard to see how a hand-rolled solution could be any better - for one thing, how will gettext handle all the built-in strings supplied by Qt?

@ekhumoro So in other words, you recommend me to use PyQt's translation mechanism?

It seems far less work to adopt a well-established Qt-based solution. There are tools for converting po files to Qt's ts format, so you're not forced to use Qt Linguist. Your problem is almost entirely coding-related, rather than tooling-related. It will be much, much easier to transition your code to use the Qt APIs than develop something from scratch using gettext.

Now my problem is, how do I live-switch languages in PyQt6's QTranslator so it actually shows up in the UI immediately? There seems to be no .retranslateUI() even though Qt in C++ seems to have it.

Well, you obviously have to write it yourself, as stated in the answer to the question you linked to above. Did you read the code? There's no magic bullet here. Neither Qt nor gettext caches the original strings, so there's no way to undo a previous translation. You need to set the new translator, and then reapply all your retranslateUI slots. This could be done by connecting them to a custom signal emitted by a handler that watches for language-change events.

Could you expand upon your custom event idea in an answer? Would also help in marking this question as answered.

Honestly, I think your question is already answered by the link above. A custom signal would only be worthwhile if you have multiple retranslateUI slots distributed across several modules. It would simply entail emitting a signal in the changeEvent handler, rather than calling the slots directly as in the linked answer. This only requires a few simple lines of code, so I don't think it's worth repeating (see this answer, for example).

The GNU gettext API wasn't designed to support changing locale on the fly. Its main use case is to select a locale depending on the user's preferences. Users configure their operating system to use a particular locale. You are a developer and you want to see that your application supports multiple locales. But in order to see that, just start your application with different environment variables. Your users will never ever ask for that feature. It's mission creep.

The longer answer is: Yes, there are use cases where you want to switch locale at runtime and gettext isn't optimized for that because the libc setlocale call isn't optimized for it. But there are solutions for this problem depending on the use case. But your problem is not a use case. It's just not really necessary.

Does your /usr/bin/unzip has an option --locale=LOCALE so that you can make it say "Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" instead of "No such file or directory" for ENOENT? And if not, did you ever miss that feature? Don't get me wrong, if you are on Linux, you can make your /usr/bin/ls/libc speak German by just setting LANGUAGE/LANG/LC_ALL/LC_MESSAGES to de but that is not application-specific.

@GuidoFlohr The purpose of my 7-zip GUI is to (as exactly as possible) replicate the behaviour of the official one. And the official one can switch languages live, as well as almost every other program I've ever used that has a language setting (like e.g. Firefox, which is in Gtk tho).

@Lampe2020, fair enough. But I think that there is no easy way to achieve that. You must iterate over all widgets and call setText() on them. From Qt's point of view, it just receives a string as the label, when you construct the icons. Alternatively, force a restart of the application after a language switch.
